# How to move multiple files using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to move all files/folders in one directory that contain some words and move them to another?  So for example all files/folders called 'Testing this' and moving them to another folder?  I try the following but its not working?  The words 'testing this' could be shown anywhere in the file name.

```
   Dim directory = "C:\Test\"
        For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "testing this", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(filename, "C:\Test\Old\" & "testing this")
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the My.Computer.FIlesSystem.MoveFile can move only one file for each call.
You need to build a loop around your source directory and move each file one by one

```
Dim sourceDir = "C:\test"
For Each file As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles( sourceDir, _

    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*testing this*")

    Dim destPath = file.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1)
    Dim destFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)

    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(file, _
               System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\Test\Old", destPath, destFile ))
Next
```

Comment: hello, it says that filename is not declared?

Comment: I have used the original variable used by your code above. You can change it to a fixed string.

Comment: thanks mate, just one more thing i would have liked to move all files and folders that contain "*testing this*" and not only the files, is that possible at all?

Comment: You need to recreate the destination name changing the source path with the substitution path. Answer updated

Comment: hi steve, sorry i think you have misunderstood me, I didnt mean to move each file in its own folder in the destination.  Say the Test folder had a folder inside it called "testing this 2" both your codes wouldnt move this folder.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes I understand, but this is not possible with MoveFiles (Files not Directory). The original folder remains in the source dir. Perhaps a second loop that calls System.IO.Directory.Delete (not very elegant but...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcards in the GetFiles method.

So:

```
Dim directory = "C:\Test\"
        For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*testing this*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(filename, "C:\Test\Old\" & "testing this")
        Next
```

Comment: cheers buddy, will give that a go I was thinking about that but had it the wrong wa around *"testing this"*

Comment: hi mate that works thanks, another question please how do i copy over the same name of the file/folder I tried the following coding but get an error My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(filename, "C:\Test\Old\) the error is The given file path ends with a directory separator character.
Parameter name: destinationFileName

Comment: If my answer solves your question, mark it as answer please. I think @Steve's answer below solves your other question.